# Get a list of items as result of a Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

All my Hibernate classes have a method similar to this:

```
@Transactional
public DadosUsuario findById(int id) {
    log.debug("getting DadosUsuario instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        DadosUsuario instance = (DadosUsuario) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(DadosUsuario.class, id);
        log.debug("get successful");
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

where the result is one row from table DadosUsuario with the specificed id. I want a variation from this example, where I could make this search for the other fields from this table (which is fk_usuario, fk_dados and conteudo).

I try something like that:

```
@Transactional
public DadosUsuario findByUsuario(Usuario user) {
    log.debug("getting DadosUsuario instance with id: " + user.getLogin());
    try {
        DadosUsuario instance = (DadosUsuario) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(DadosUsuario.class, user);
        log.debug("get successful");
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

but don't work (the methog get don't accept the type Usuario as second parameter). I also try using a sql query, following the example from this article:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/

but also don't get a functional method. Someone knows how I can accomplish an implementation of a methos like this:

```
public List<DadosUsuario> findByUsuario(Usuario user) {
```

where the return will be a list of user's data (DadosUsuario)?

**UPDATE**

final code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<DadosUsuario> findByUsuario(Usuario user) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
            "select * from dados_usuario where fk_usuario = :id_usuario")
            .addEntity(DadosUsuario.class)
            .setParameter("id_usuario", user.getId());
            List<DadosUsuario> allUsers = query.list();
    return allUsers;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to return a list of objects of some kind the hibernate query should look like:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    Query q = currentSession().createQuery("from User");
    List<User> allUsers = (List<User>) q.list();
    return allUsers;
}
```

Where `User` is the name of the hibernate class that matches the table you want to get data from, you will have to change the following to suit your needs.

or you could have something like:

```
public List<DadosUsuario> findByUsuario(Usuario user) {
    Query q = currentSession().createQuery("from DadosUsuario d 
                  where d.id = user.id");
    List<DadosUsuario> allUsers = (List<DadosUsuario>) q.list();
    return allUsers;
}
```

I hope this much clue suffices.

Comment: thanks by the answer. I mix your sugestion with the code from article I quoted in the question, and get the code I add to question.